# korn vs bash exit code

Tags: bash, unix, ksh, exit-code, mks

I have the following problem:

- I have some test scripts that previously were run with ksh (from [MKS Toolkit](http://www.mkssoftware.com/))
- The scripts will need to remain unmodified (not a single character will be changed).
- I will use bash (from Mingw/Msys) to run these scripts.

The problem is in the following:

This works fine in KornShell (ksh) but doesn't work in bash:

```
typeset -i errorCode
errorCode=10
exit errorCode
```

I need to modify the script like this (note the $ sign):

```
typeset -i errorCode
errorCode=10
exit $errorCode
```

Is there a way to make the code to be compilable with bash without making the chnage I mentioned?

Thanks

Comment: No version of ksh or its variants that I have access to work without a dollar sign on the variable in the `exit` statement. Ksh 93 takes it as 0 and `mksh` and `pdksh` complain that it's a "bad number". It must be something specific to the version of ksh in the MKS Toolkit.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson yes, it is with ksh from mks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also do this before executing the ksh script in bash

```
#!/bin/bash
exit ()
{
    unset -f exit
    if expr match "$1" '^[-|+|0-9|.][.0-9]*$' &> /dev/null ; then
            exit "$1"
    fi
    exit
}
source ./the_ksh_script
```

to override exit.
This example is compatible with the original code, i.e. gives exit code of 0.

Second example

```
exit () {
 unset -f exit
 eval rc2=\$$1
 rc1=$1
 for rc in "$rc1" "$rc2"
  do
   if expr match "$rc" '^[-|+|0-9|.][.0-9]*$' &> /dev/null ; then
    exit "$rc"
   fi
  done
 exit
}

source ./the_ksh_script
```

will produce the exit code 10, probably what the original script intends.

Comment: Ok, I understand your example; but how do I find the exit code? Because I need it

Comment: your original ksh code exit errorCode actually gives exit code 0 when running under ksh, isn't that what you want? or you want the actual value in errorCode to be to exit code. I think the original code has a bug, it just doesn't produce a error under ksh. So this example is bug compatible to the original ksh.

Comment: regarding the part where the return code is 0 ... I'm afraid that this ksh shell from MKS works file also with `exit intName` instead of working only with `exit $intName`. This is why I needed this "hack" in order to keep the scripts unmodified.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your code is in a file named **foo.sh**, you can wrap it with process substitution. For example:

```
bash <(sed 's/errorCode$/$&/' foo.sh)
```

Bash interprets the modified code as read from the file descriptor, and the exit status of the subshell is set as expected.

```
$ echo $?
10
```

Comment: wow, good one! Nice to learn something everyday. Good luck to all.